# Stripping and renaming files

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have written some Python modifying existing code to run through some JSON files and strip out some text. The end result should be saving the now edited file with the same file name "- clean.json" at the end.

I already have the code that loops through the input path, and all JSON files complete. I have also completed and tested that each file does open and the desired text is removed.

The final area is where I need help, how do I now take that updated file and save it back with an updated name. That updated name being -clean.json

All help is appreciated, script is included below:

```
def normalize_file(file):
    global line_number
    for line in file:
        line_number += 1
        json_object = json.loads(line)
        logging.info("hi")
        if not isinstance(json_object, dict):
            logging.error('%s: Top level record must be a dict but was a %s',
                         line_number, type(json_object))
            continue
        try:
            normalized_dict = normalize_dict(json_object)
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error('%s: %s', line_number, e)
            continue
        json.dump(normalized_dict, sys.stdout)
        print()
    logging.info("Processed %s lines", line_number)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    logging.info("hi")
    input_path = input("Enter path to JSON files->")
    json_folder_path = os.path.join(input_path)
    json_files = [pos_json for pos_json in os.listdir(input_path) if pos_json.endswith('.json')]
    print(json_files)
    for index, js in enumerate(json_files):
        with open(os.path.join(input_path,js)) as json_file:
            normalize_file(json_file)
```

Comment: Please reduce your code to a minimum, highlighting where exactly you need help. As it is, your code has several issues - it is unclear which one you need help with. For example, you ignore the user input, defying 1. You never *open* any files, so how do you know that 3 is working? You are loading *several* JSON from each file in a fragile manner, but your description implies otherwise.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi - understood, i have posted my updated code. the main body and function it calls only. I have also simplified the question I believe. Thanks for your feedback.